# È corretto l'uso del verbo "portare" in questo tipo di costruzioni frasali?

Tags: grammar

"Lo porto lì sulle spalle.

Il punto è che questa frase ha un doppio complemento di luogo uno di moto a luogo e l'altro di stato in luogo, essendo che portare potrebbe significare:

1)  "Fare arrivare qualcuno o qualcosa in un luogo o ad una persona"

Quindi frasi come:

"Portalo in cantina"

"Portalo a me"

2) "Trasportare  su di sè un peso"

Quindi frasi come:

"Porta lo zaino sulle spalle"

"Porta la valigia in mano"

Ora, non se so la mia analisi è corretta ed è per questo che vorrei una smentita o una conferma che possa togliermi il dubbio.

PS: io per non sbagliare direi:
"Lo porto lì portandolo/reggendolo sulle spalle".

Comment: Non c'è problema: una frase può avere parecchi complementi. Prendo un [esempio da questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=elfWOVRqb7wC&pg=PA65&dq=%22a+casa+in+macchina%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic6vbHgNLjAhUMJBoKHRKEAnkQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22a%20casa%20in%20macchina%22&f=false): «Le otto ore di lavoro si trascorrono in ufficio o in fabbrica, e poi si torna a casa in macchina, in autobus, in treno spesso in mezzo alla folla». Non c'è nessun problema a dire "si torna a casa in treno in mezzo alla folla".

Comment: Non riuscirò mai a capire perché gli italiani si complicano tanto la vita cercando di classificare i complementi con tutti questi nomi. Per fortuna, io questo non l'ho dovuto studiare mai.

Comment: Il linguaggio "naturale” è ambiguo e spesso richiede un contesto per comprendere il significato di una frase: "la vecchia porta la sbarra" è l'esempio tipico (*porta* può essere sia sostantivo sia verbo).

Comment: Potresti cercare di dare un titolo un po' più descrittivo alla tua domanda?

Comment: Nakamura: Sono d'accordo con @FedericoPoloni perché le domande che si chiedono su questo sito devono essere anche utili per altri utenti nel futuro. Quindi, è importante che i titoli siano informativi del contenuto della domanda. Per esempio, il titolo "È possibile usare due complimenti di luogo in una stessa frase?" andrebbe bene?

Comment: @Charo: cercherò di cambiare il titolo con uno più comprensibile.

Comment: Non avere timore, @Nakamura, a usare questo frequentissimo verbo contemporaneamente nei due significati che hai indicato. Va bene usarlo una sola volta (la frase che useresti ha o una ripetizione o un verbo poco usato): chi ti ascolta capirà che con un complemento dici che sposti un oggetto, e con l’altro che l’oggetto è su di te. Logicamente, chi ti ascolta saprà cosa è “lo” e dov’è “lì” perché ne avrete parlato prima.

Comment: Diresti "Vado a Milano in treno" o "Vado a Milano andandoci in treno"? Stessa cosa.

Comment: @Benedetta: Potresti convertire il tuo commento in una risposta, magari aggiungendo qualcosa sul fatto che un verbo  può reggere più di un complemento senza problema, come nell'esempio di DaG?

Comment: @Charo: ho scritto la risposta; spero che per DaG vada bene il modo in cui ho integrato il suo esempio con «andare».

Answer (score 3):

Si può usare senza timore questo frequentissimo verbo contemporaneamente nei due significati indicati nella domanda. Va bene usarlo una sola volta (la frase proposta nel PS ha o una ripetizione: *porto … portandolo*; o un verbo poco usato: *reggendolo*): chi ascolta capirà che con un complemento si dice che si sposta un oggetto, e con l’altro che l’oggetto è “su” chi parla. Logicamente, chi ascolta saprà cosa è “lo” e dov’è “lì” perché se ne sarà parlato prima.

Medesimo discorso si può fare per altri verbi, ad es. il verbo *andare*, come proposto da @DaG nei commenti: «Vado a Milano in treno», e non «Vado a Milano andandoci in treno».